# Event handler for button object in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a code for a hangman game that includes buttons. I'm exercising with classes so my code looks this way. What I'm trying to do is somehow connect my button to recognise a letter from a random variable and replace it with my displayed underscores. So far i have this.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

actors = ["NICK NOLTE", "MEL GIBSON", "PATRICK STEWART", "CHRISTIAN BALE", "ARNOLD SCHWARZENEGGER",
      "MATTHEW MCCONAUGHEY", "MERYL STREEP", "JOHNNY DEPP", "ANGELINA JOLIE", "CAMERON DIAZ", "AL PACINO",
      "ANDY GARCIA", "JULIA ROBERTS"]

letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
       "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

class MyButtons:
    def __init__(self, master):
        buttonsFrame = Frame(master)
        buttonsFrame.grid(row=0)

        x = 0
        y = 0
        for i in letters:
            button = Button(buttonsFrame, text=i, width=5, command=self.onclick(i))
            button.grid(row=x, column=y)
            y += 1
            if y > 3:
                y = 0
                x += 1

    def onclick(self, k):
        def click():
            print (k)
        return click

actor = random.choice(actors)

root = Tk()

guessFrame = Frame(root)
guessFrame.grid(row=1)

buton = MyButtons(root)

def underscores():
    total = ""
    for i in actor:
        if i == " ":
            i = "     "
            total += i
        else:
            i = "_"
            total += i
    return total

label = Label(guessFrame, text=underscores())
label.grid(row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

So, something that I see wrong right away is your command for your button. Here's what it should look like.

```
button = Button(buttonsFrame, text=i, width=5, command=lambda k=i: self.onclick(k)))
```

The reason that you need the lambda if you are using self.onclick(i) with the parenthesis is that you are passing that function to another function. See if that works, and if it doesn't please tell me.

Comment: That's not quite right, Anthony. The right way is `command=lambda k=i: self.onclick(k)`. This binds the argument to the command at the time the command is defined.